# Python: Theme writable site building with Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

i am writing a web site using python-flask and i got some problems.My purpose is that every user can be write a theme.I've solved theme engine part.My problem starts with the directories.

All we know in flask there is two directories named `templates` and `static`.When a user uploads his/her theme should i put it into `templates` or `static`?

In the theme user uploaded,there is both `assets(js etc.)` and `html` files.If i put them into `templates` dir i can not access the `css,js etc.` files.

Otherwise if i put them into `static` folder,jinja2 can not find the `html` files and some guys say don't put `html` files into static folder.

Now what should i do?Should i add another folder named `userthemes etc.`?

Now,my directory is this:

```
/python
   /static
   /templates
     login.html
     admin_page.html
   app.py
```

The `index.html` will be appear when an user uploads his/her theme.If you can help,i will be glad.Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [Flask-Themes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Themes)?  If so, what was it lacking (so that we know what your particular issue is)?

Comment: My issue is could not make it work with anyway,is not there anyway?

Comment: @SeanVieira See my answer, it doesn't work/has a bug atm.

Answer (score 2):

I do acknowledge that this question was asked a year ago, but the problem is still there. Flask-Themes doesn't work so far..because of this I had to find a way to do it by myself.

Actually it's a trivial process.

A clean structure is a MUST for later maintenance (even if it's a one-author project).

So, trying to adapt Özcan's structure, to have a multiple template configuration, we could have a structure like this:

```
/python
_ _ _ _app.py
_ _ _ _config.py
______/templates
________________/default
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _index.html
________________/custom
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _index.html
```

I don't know what code is/was on his app files, but I'll suppose that in the **app.py** there is something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

import config
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/templates/' + config.Config.ACTIVE_THEME)

@app.route('/')
def main():
  return render_template('index.html')

if '__name__' == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

The config.py like this:

```
class Config(object):
    ACTIVE_THEME='default'
```

The **default** theme index.html in the **templates** folder may look like this:

```
<head>
  # We have the ability to include the css from the current path instead of having a separate static folder
  <style type='text/css'> {% include 'style.css' %} </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> This is the "default" theme </h1>
</body>
```

And the **custom** theme index.html like this:

```
<head>
  <style type='text/css'> {% include 'style.css' %} </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> This is the "custom" theme </h1>
</body>
```

Now, visiting `127.0.0.1:5000` will show "This is the "default" theme" because in fact the default theme is loaded.

To change this you'd have to edit the config file in the following way:

```
class Config(object):
    # Set ACTIVE_THEME from default to custom
    ACTIVE_THEME='custom'
```

Save the changes, reload the page and you should see "This is the "custom" theme".

This is a very basic "hack" but I suggest working with blueprints if you're serious about your app, and other than this there's the inconvenient of having to mantain 2 config files instead of one.

To avoid these problem I'm using blueprints and a good structuring of the app.

For example I define the config after the app is initialized, so instead of being like this:

```
import config
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=/templates/' + config.Config.ACTIVE_THEME)
```

It is like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.Config')
```

And in a separate file with all the views, the following line at the top:

```
# doing an "import app" would raise an error because of it being a circular import
import config
active_theme = config.Config.ACTIVE_THEME

# Watch out for the second argument as it seems to add a prefix to successive defined arguments. In fact you could swap the "themes" part to it and remove it from the third argument, but I prefer to leave it like this to avoid future headaches.
posts = Blueprint('posts', '', template_folder='templates/' + active_theme + '/post')
```

It can also be extended by other means such as user session, database config etc.

Hope this helps someone.